# VBA Replace str with line break

Tags: vba

I have a string:

```
x = "some text [y] some text"
```

and I want to replace '[y]' with a line break. I have tried:

```
x = Replace(x, "[y]", "Chr(13)")
```

but the result is the text equivilent, rather than a break:

```
some text Chr(13) some text
```

Is there a way to Replace a string with a line break?

Comment: `Chr(13)` without quotes or `vbCr`

Comment: Thanks. The without quotes does not work quite so well - a wrapping issue I think - but the vbCr does the trick. Put as an answer and will tick.

Comment: Ok, so you can use `VbCr`. Interesting. Presumably, Windows adds the line feed automatically when you do a carriage return. I'd still recommend that you use `VbCrLf` as Microsoft does; you may get some strange results in some Unicode situations otherwise.

Comment: Excellent advise and spot on.

Comment: Where do you want to break the line - in a text file (in which case vbCrLf on Windows) or in an Excel cell (in which case vbLf) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sial has said, don't use quotes. `Chr` is a function, like, say, `InStr`, not a literal string. So:

```
x = "some text" & VbCrLf & "some more text."
```

Now, it's important to distinguish whether your particular operating system uses CR, LF, or CRLF to go to a new line. Windows generally uses CRLF, although I'd have to experiment to find out whether just CR will fail to feed a new line in VBA. I'd say it's safer to go with `VbCrLf`.

If you prefer (although I can't see why one would), you can do this :

```
x - "some text" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "some more text."
```

For more info on newline, see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using x = Replace(x, "[y]", vbCrLf) which has worked perfectly in Excel.